# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la clase de un elemento con JavaScript o JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

recorro a los expertos para que me orienten un poco ya le dado muchas vueltas y no logro conseguirlo, resulta que tengo una tipo de publicación en wordpres necesito cambiar un div class

```
<div class="content"> </div>
```

a

```
<div class="content2"> </div>
```

intente de la siguiente manera

```
document.getElementsByClassName("content").classList.add('content2');
```

pero no tengo logro hacer el cambio

necesito que este cambio se realice a la hora de cargar la pagina.

Comment: excelente tu respuesta muchas gracias, sin embargo no logro eliminar content, queda de la siguiente manera:  <div class="content content2"></div>, estoy realizando las pruebas desde la consola del navegador, en la respuesta muestra: undefined, alguna sugerencia?, gracias de nuevo..

Comment: lo siento por el inconveniente, necesito procesarlo a la hora de cargar la pagina...

Comment: Si bien estas con los motodos remove/add, también podrías utilizar el método [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) de classList que lo que hace es remover si lo tiene o agregar la clase si no la tiene (o sea alterna la clase). También es útil en determinas circunstancias. Dale una mirada

Answer (score 1):

**1) Guardar en una variable el elemento**

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].classList;
```

**2) Remover la clase deseada**

```
element.remove('content')
```

**3) Añadir la nueva clase**

```
element.add('content2')
```

Comment: excelente función tal como debería, muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: Me alegra que haya solucionado tu problema, si lo consideras podrías marcar la respuesta como respuesta aceptada o útil para indicar a los demás usuarios que tengas la misma dificultad que ha solucionado la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: @Triby es porque la variable *element* no es un elemento sino la referencia *classList* (mira en la asignacion)

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez, cierto, no me fijé en la asignación. :-p

Answer (score 1):

Si bien lo podemos realizar con jQuery, con Javascript podriamos utilizar [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) y [toggle de classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Si bien utilizas  los métodos **remove/add** de **classList** , también podrías utilizar el método [toggle de classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) que lo que hace es remover si lo tiene o agregar la clase si no la tiene (o sea alterna la clase). También es útil en determinas circunstancias. Dale una mirada. Además también puedas pasarle un "evaluador" como segundo parámetro .
También podrías utilizar el método [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) que esta en la mayoría de los [browser actuales (puedes mirar "Can I Use")](https://caniuse.com/queryselector) donde puedes enviar un selector al igual que jQuery pero no con todos los "superpoderes"

Ejemplo:

```
function changeCssClassVersion2() {
  var elemFirst = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="content"]')[0];

  elemFirst.classList.toggle('content');
  elemFirst.classList.toggle('content2');
 }
```

Lo ideal seria que el código sea mas genérico, es decir no que vaya directo al primer elemento sino que itere en todo lo que se "encontró" con el selector. Quedaría algo así:

```
function changeCssClassVersion2() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="content"]');
  
  for (const i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 
  {
    var elem = elements[i];
    elem.classList.toggle('content');
    elem.classList.toggle('content2');
  }
}
```

Puedes probarlo en el siguiente ejemplo sencillo

- https://jsfiddle.net/fernandezja/65bzx4nk/

```js
function changeCssClassVersion1() {
  var elemFirst = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
  
  elemFirst.classList.remove("content");
  elemFirst.classList.add('content2');
}

function changeCssClassVersion2() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="content"]');
  
  for (const i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 
  {
    var elem = elements[i];
    elem.classList.toggle('content');
    elem.classList.toggle('content2');
  }
}

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', changeCssClassVersion2, false);
```

```css
.content {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
}

.content2 {
  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"> Starwars</div> 
<button id="btn">Change Css Class</button>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía